# react js setstate inside event inline function

Tags: reactjs, select, setstate

i want to validate table dropdowns for duplicate values

///////////////

[image]

///////////////

i want to do set error  property in setState for table dropdown duplicate value , i tried to did it inside inline function . but i think this way is not possible .

```
    </TableRow>
{
    item.map(k => (
        <TableRow >

            <TableCell >
                <select  onChange={function(e){
                     item.forEach(k1 => {
                        if(k1.key===e.target.value)
                        {

                       this.setState({
                          err:'duplicate'
                         })                 
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            k.key=e.target.value
                            this.setState({
                             err:''
                               })
                        }
                     })
                     }}>

            </select>

            </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
```

if i tried to create and bind function in class , changing one dropdown whould change all dropdown 
Please suggest how can i do the state in inline function

Comment: Where does k come from in `k.key=e.target.value`?

Comment: k coems from  item.map(k => ( in initial lines

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to do this inline at all. I see your motivation to try to do it inline since you need access to `item` from the loop, but you can send that element to the function without it being inline:

```
const onSelectchange = (e, k) => {
   item.forEach(k1 => {
      if(k1.key===e.target.value)
      {

     this.setState({
        err:'duplicate'
       })                 
          console.log(err)
      }
      else
      {
          k.key=e.target.value
          this.setState({
           err:''
             })
      }
   })
 }


return(</TableRow>
  {
  item.map(k => (
  <TableCell >
      <select  onChange={(e) => onSelectchange(e, k)}>

  </select>

  </TableCell>
</TableRow>)
```

You can create an inline anonymous function and pass your `e` and `item` to the function and then execute it as you would inline.

If you're worried about "performance" of having an inline anonymous function, don't. That's a sort of myth.

Make sure you have no syntax errors as right now the code is not correct to simply copy paste.

Comment: but in your function k.key is not accepting .. it says .. k is undefined

Comment: i have tested this function .. it is not working . is it working on your side ?

Comment: I made a rookie mistake! `item` will be undefined when the function is triggered. Editing it now.

Comment: Edited @NeerajVerma, the function was sending `item` which you should have access to inside the component, it had to pass `k` instead which is what you need from the loop.